# Drilldown Map using JSON file Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to do map drilldown using Highcharts by following this US Map Drilldown example : [US Map Drilldown Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/map-drilldown/)

This is the sample of my drilldown javascript file

```
var data = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/my/my-all']),
    separators = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/my/my-all'], 'mapline'),
    // Some responsiveness
    small = $('#container').width() < 400;

// Set drilldown pointers
$.each(data, function (i) {
    this.drilldown = this.properties['hc-key'];
    this.value = i; // Non-random bogus data
});

// Instantiate the map
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            drilldown: function (e) {
                if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                    var chart = this,
                        mapKey = 'countries/my/' + e.point.drilldown + '-all',
                        // Handle error, the timeout is cleared on success
                        fail = setTimeout(function () {
                            if (!Highcharts.maps[mapKey]) {
                                chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-frown"></i> Failed loading ' + e.point.name);
                                fail = setTimeout(function () {
                                    chart.hideLoading();
                                }, 1000);
                            }
                        }, 3000);

                    // Show the spinner
                    chart.showLoading('<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-3x"></i>'); // Font Awesome spinner

                    // Load the drilldown map
                    $.getScript('https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/' + mapKey + '.js', function () {

                        data = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps[mapKey]);

                        // Set a non-random bogus value
                        $.each(data, function (i) {
                            this.value = i;
                        });

                        // Hide loading and add series
                        chart.hideLoading();
                        clearTimeout(fail);
                        chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, {
                            name: e.point.name,
                            data: data,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '{point.name}'
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }

                this.setTitle(null, { text: e.point.name });
            },
            drillup: function () {
                this.setTitle(null, { text: '' });
            }
        }
```

**This is sample code for states.json**

```
 "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "MY.SA",
      "properties": {
        "hc-group": "admin1",
        "hc-middle-x": 0.32,
        "hc-middle-y": 0.6,
        "hc-key": "my-sa",
        "hc-a2": "SA",
        "labelrank": "6",
        "hasc": "MY.SA",
        "alt-name": "North Borneo",
        "woe-id": "2346310",
        "subregion": null,
        "fips": "MY16",
        "postal-code": "SA",
        "name": "Sabah",
        "country": "Malaysia",
        "type-en": "State",
        "region": null,
        "longitude": "117.095",
        "woe-name": "Sabah",
        "latitude": "5.31115",
        "woe-label": "Sabah, MY, Malaysia",
        "type": "State"
      },
```

**This is sample code for district in district.json**

```
 {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "GID_0": "MYS",
        "NAME_0": "Malaysia",
        "GID_1": "MYS.13_1",
        "NAME_1": "Sabah",
        "NL_NAME_1": null,
        "GID_2": "MYS.13.1_1",
        "NAME_2": "Beaufort",
        "VARNAME_2": null,
        "NL_NAME_2": null,
        "TYPE_2": "Daerah",
        "ENGTYPE_2": "District",
        "CC_2": null,
        "HASC_2": "MY.SA.BF",
        "ISO": "MY-12",
        "ISO_district": "MY-12.1"
      },
```

I need to use getJSON function right? Can someone help me how to do the declaration in the javascript file?

Comment: Could you prepare a jsfiddle example of the map that you already have?

Comment: This one : [https://jsfiddle.net/syazwan0913/43eryc7g/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/syazwan0913/43eryc7g/6/)

Comment: The problem is that you want to get a script from this link: https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/my/my-ph-all.js which is empty because Highcharts doesn't provide mapdata/countries/my/my-ph-all.js file. Instead of this piece of code try to use getJSON to get your data.

Comment: So I need to create my-ph-all.js file?

Comment: You need to create a data to plot map using those data. It can be an external file or object in your js file....check the example data here https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-ut-all.js.

Comment: Means I need to follow the code format from here [code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-ut-all.js](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/us-ut-all.js) , right?

Comment: Take a look at this articles: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-maps, https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps

Comment: I tried to follow the example from here : [Drilldown Texas](http://jsfiddle.net/syazwan0913/jLswoxg1/2/). This is the map that I am doing : [Drilldown Malaysia](http://jsfiddle.net/syazwan0913/v0f9z5pn/)

Comment: I got it already. Thanks